# Creating report using Jasper reports and Spring @Async

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

Hi I'm trying to create a report using Spring and Jasper reports in Java. I'm attempting the report creation inside a `@Async` method in Spring. Are there any limitations when it comes to this scenario? Since I'm getting a Jasper issue about not having a certain font; which wasn't there before. Any clue how this could happen?